# Developing recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I'm having difficulty developing recurrence relations for algorithms and was wondering if anyone could confirm my answer to a question. The algorithm is

```
int result = strange(n);
public static int strange (int n)
{
   if (n <= 1)
       {
        return n;
       }
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
        sum += strange (n/2);
       }
   return sum;
}
```

From what I understand the relation that I got is

```
T(1) = 1
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
```

But I'm not confident that this is the answer. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Almost there - it's `T(n) = nT(n/2) + n` as each iteration of the loop recurses then does an `O(1)` operation (addition) - so `n(T(n/2) + 1)`.

Comment: That makes sense, so basically when figuring out the relation I would ignore the first 'if' statement if n > 1 since in this case T(1) = 1?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That `if` statement forms the base case.